# One of two animations doesn't work

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a view hidden at the beggining (it's visible but below the screen, so the user cannot see it) and the first time the user clicks on a marker, the view goes up with an animation and the user can see it. When the user clicks other marker, the View should move down (to its original position below the screen, hidden), then change the text of the TextView it has and finally move it up again with the new info.

Everything works fine but the down animation; the view just dissappear and does the up movement again. I have tried Animation and TranslateAnimation with the same result.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    if (!anyMarkerSelected) {

        textViewNombre.setText(establecimiento.getNombreEstablecimiento());
        textViewDireccion.setText(establecimiento.getNombreVia());
        textViewDescripcion.setText(establecimiento.getNumeroVia());

        view.startAnimation(animationUp);
        animationUp.setFillAfter(true);

        mapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
        anyMarkerSelected = true;

        return true;

        } else {

        view.startAnimation(animationDown);  //This animation is not working
        animationDown.setFillAfter(true);

        textViewNombre.setText(establecimiento.getNombreEstablecimiento());
        textViewDireccion.setText(establecimiento.getNombreVia());
        textViewDescripcion.setText(establecimiento.getNumeroVia());

        view.startAnimation(animationUp);
        animationUp.setFillAfter(true);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And the XML files of the animations are:

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="110%" />
```

---

```
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-110%" />
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe just toggle the visibility from View.GONE to View.VISIBLE?

Comment: The view is not truly gone or invisible, it's just outside the screen (but still View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting 2 different animations at the same time, looks like it is defaulting to the later one. You need to put them both into an AnimationSet and put a setStartOffset on your down animation.

Here is some example code:

```
//only takes an animation listener and with that you need implement all the methods
   public void doViewAnimationSet(){
    TranslateAnimation transTo= new TranslateAnimation(0, -mLittleChef.getX()/2, 0, 0);
    TranslateAnimation transBack= new TranslateAnimation(0, mLittleChef.getX()/2, 0, 0);
    transTo.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration/2);
    transBack.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration/2);
    transTo.setStartOffset(0);
    transBack.setStartOffset(transTo.getDuration());
    AnimationSet transSet= new AnimationSet(true);
    transSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    transSet.addAnimation(transTo);
    transSet.addAnimation(transBack);
    transSet.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            simpleLock= false;
        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    mLittleChef.startAnimation(transSet);
    //another way to start your set animation:
    //set.setTarget(mLittleChef);
    //set.start();
}
```

You can read more: [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/2d-animation-for-android-series-comparing-and-contrasting-different-ways-of-doing-the-same-part-II)

Answer (score 0):

You also have a spelling error on the following line:
  textViewDireccion.setText(establecimiento.getNombreVia());

Should be:

textViewDirection vs. Direccion..